# Does an eclipse plugin come with it's own dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have an eclipse plugin in which I want to use  the latest `CDT` plugin extension points ( I have a `.target` file where I configure the version).
Assume that my plugin is installed in an `eclipse based product` (with a different `.target` file) which comes with an older `CDT` version (which doesn't have the extension points required by my plugin).

What is happening when the plugin is installed in that product?
Does the plugin come with it's own `CDT` dependencies and there won't be any problems?
Will eclipse load the CDT plugin based on the requirements of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MANIFEST.MF of a plug-in specifies its dependencies. Eclipse will resolve these when it loads the plug-in from the currently installed plug-ins.

The `Require-Bundle` in the MANIFEST.MF specifies which other plug-ins are required and can specify which versions of the plug-in are acceptable.

The MANIFEST.MF can also use `Import-Package` to name packages that it needs without saying which plug-in contains them,

Comment: So anyhow, the requirements from `MANIFEST.MF` of the plugin should be available in the `eclipse product` where the plugin is installed, right?

Comment: Depending on exactly how you install the plugin Eclipse may try to resolve missing dependencies by looking in known repositories. Otherwise it will fail to install with unresolved dependencies.

Comment: I just create at the `configuration` folder level a `links` folder with a `*.link` file inside it which contains the path to the plugin ( e.g. `path=d:/ts_mirr/a_swatt/v1.10/eclipse`)

Comment: It will fail most likely

Comment: You may even have to start Eclipse with the -clean option to get it to notice that file. It will certainly not try to find missing dependencies.